# Constant baseline position

Tags: line-spacing

Is there a way to set a constant base line position? For example, to the baseline of the first line under any circumstances (even if the lines bump each other) started with 1 cm from the top of the page, the second - from 2cm and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0cm,bottom=.7cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\topskip}{1cm}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-\maxdimen}

\def\bigfrac{\frac{\;\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\mathstrut}\;}
  {\;\displaystyle\frac{\mathstrut3}{4}\;}}

\def\bigroot{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\bigfrac}}}}}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{1cm}

\kant*[1] $\bigfrac$ \kant*[2] $\bigroot$ \kant[3-4]
\end{document}
```

The result is too ugly to be shown. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just set `\lineskiplimit` to `-\maxdimen`, or `-10000pt` for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\fontsize{18}{12}\selectfont
\lineskiplimit-\maxdimen
\lipsum

\end{document}
```